# Swift SpriteKit GameplayKit check GKStateMachine does not equal state

Tags: swift

I have just finished converting my game using the Entity and Component base architecture (GameplayKit) that apple introduced in iOS9.

I cannot figure out how to check that a current state (GKStateMachine) does not equal a state.
Say I want to check that the currentState is equal to my GameOverState, I would say this

```
 if self.stateMachine.currentState is GameOverState {...
```

How would I check if the current state does not equal GameOverState, the "... is ..." sytanx is new to me so I am not sure how to call it.

Comment: I've not my mac with me. But,  !GameOverState works? However you can use guard let gameover = self.stateMachine.currentState is GameOverState where gameover == false else {return}

Comment: Hey thanks for your tip. Unfortunately !GameOverState does not work, I tried as !.. as well. Your second suggestion works although I had to slightly change the syntax as I got a compiler error. I call it "if let gameOver: Bool = self.stateMachine....." and than if !gameOver .... Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into this issue myself. It doesn't seem like ther is an inverse to `is`, so the only option I could see was to wrap the conditional statement to invert the boolean. So you would do like the following...

```
if !(self.stateMachine.currentState is GameOverState) {...
```

I found it hard to find documentation... so for yours, and others reference:
[Documentation on the `is` operator (section titled "Type-Casting Operators")](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH32-ID383)

Comment: Thank you. I actually saw this the other day in DemoBots and tried it again and it still didnt work. Now with your answer I finally know why, it turns out you need the brackets and cannot just say !self.stateMachine.....

Comment: Indeed. This is because you need to convert the whole boolean evaluation to the opposite. Imagine 0 OR 1. !0 OR 1 is very different to !(0 OR 1).